# Render both components independently

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, nuxt3

I have two simple components ...

```
  1. app.vue
  2. pages/xyz.vue
```

I want to render both of them independently with their respective content but seem to run into these issues ...

```
  1. Upon visiting app.vue as http://localhost:3000, I get HTTP 404
  2. Upon visiting pages/xyz.vue as http://localhost:3000/xyz, I see the content of app.vue
```

Can you please explain and help? You can clone and try with this - https://github.com/nvijayap/n3

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In app.vue add the `NuxtPage` component :

```html
<template>
  <div>
   <NuxtPage />
  </div>
</template>
```

and also add an `index.vue` component inside pages folder in order to map the home path :

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h3>Home page</h3>
  </div>
</template>
```